Apache Camel - on first failure put on retry queue and only retry on 2nd queue, transacted = true
I have a requirement to process rollbacked message on a different queue than the original. How this could be done in ActiveMQ + Apache Camel?
So I have a Queue A to consume message, and after processing I .stop() the route and reply is sent back to the reply queue, specified in the JMSReplyTo header of the message. transacted is set to true to enable it. Apparently, exchange pattern is InOut as the header JMSReplyTo is present. When error happens while processing the message, I do exchange.setRollBackOnly(true) and Camel put them back to Queue A and they stuck there waiting to be processed again. Because the redelivery config is exponential backoff, adn backoff exponential multiplier is set to 2, messages wait in queue longer and longer. That blocks other new messages and causes problem.
We want to push the retrying message to another queue B, when the first failure happens, and let retry happen only there, but we see some difficulties:

if transacted = true, even retry is only happening on 2nd queue, the original messages are not removed; seems transaction has the span across the queues and only when reply sent at last, will the original message be removed.
but if I change transacted = false, retry is not happening; after exchange.setRollbackOnly(true), leaving that bean, message is not pushed back to queue, it's just consumed and gone.

What can I do in this situation?
Some pseucode, original version:
static final String MAIN_ENDPOINT = "direct:main";
onException(SomeException.class)
    .bean(ExceptionMapper.class)
    .continue(true);

from("activemq:queue:A") // first try route
    to(MAIN_ENDPOINT);

from("activemq:queue:B")
    to(MAIN_ENDPOINT); // put retry queue message back to our route

from(MAIN_ENDPOINT)
    .errorHandler(noErrorHandler())
    .bean(Validator.class)
    .bean(BusinessBean.class)
    .stop(); // sending reply here

Originally in BusinessBean.class:
...
if (caught instanceof SomeException) {
    exchange.setRollbackOnly(true); // leaving this bean, route rolled back and pushed back to queue
    return;
}

Now changed to:
if (caught instanceof SomeException) {
    exchange.getIn().setBody(originalMessage);
    exchange.setHeader("retry", true);
    return;
}

and:
from("activemq:queue:A")
    .errorHandler(noErrorHandler())
    .bean(Validator.class)
    .bean(BusinessBean.class)
    .choice()
        .when(simple("${header.retry} == true")
            .to("activemq:queue:B") // move to retry queue
        .endChoice()
        .otherwise()
            .stop() // sending reply here
        .endChoice()
    .end();

